# Change default ARM gcc option to thumb

Tags: gcc, compilation, arm, toolchain, thumb

I want to change the behavior of the ARM toolchain `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` in my Linux machine, that the compiled code will be in `Thumb` mode as default - same as passing the `-mthumb` flag.

I came across [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html) document, which under the section of `--with-mode` describes exactly what I try to achieve. However, I couldn't understand from their explanation how can I actually set this option.

Can anyone clarify this for me, or suggest another way to achieve my goal?

Comment: You have to recompile `gcc` from sources and pass `--with-mode` option to configure script. [configure script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configure_script) [unofficial gcc sources mirror on github](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc) I think it woud be just easier to create `/usr/local/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` script that would just pass the option...

Comment: Presumably on any real project, you're using a Makefile or something similar to control compilation, in which case you can just set this in CFLAGS or whatever.  Trying to set it "permanently and globally" seems like the wrong approach.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks for the first part, now it's more clear.  For the second part - that exactly what I don't understand, what is this script, and what it supposed to contain?

Comment: @NateEldredge It's a small workaround, I tried to set the CFLAGS but for some reason, it didn't work.

Comment: Create a file `/usr/local/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` with the content `#!/bin/sh` `/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -mthumb "$@"` and add executable permissions to the file. Because `PATH` should list `/usr/local/bin` directory before `/usr/bin`, your script will chosen first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "mask" the executable file `/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` with your own script that is named the same inside `/usr/local/bin`.

- Create a file /usr/local/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
- With the content

  - `#!/bin/sh`
  - `/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -mthumb "$@"`
- Add executable permissions to /usr/local/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc

Because PATH should list `/usr/local/bin` directory before `/usr/bin`, when you type `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` without the path in your console, your script will chosen first and will execute the real `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` executable with the additional option.